# GetX: Controller for each item in a list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Using Flutter with GetX.

I have a GetX controller for items and I have a list of items.

When I use

```
final ItemController c = Get.find();
```

it uses the same controller for each item in the list and the values within every item get overwritten.

How can I get a unique controller for each item in the list?  Is there a "Key" concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite your given information is insufficient in regards with what you want to achieve, the answer of your question is: Yes! There is a concept like "Key" in GetX. You can tag your controllers or dependencies when putting like:

```
Get.put(ItemController(), tag: "yourTag")
```

And when finding:

```
final taggedController = Get.find<ItemController>(tag:"yourTag");
```